# Can CouchDB database be encrypted at rest?

Tags: encryption, couchdb, pouchdb, non-relational-database, crypto-pouch

Looking out for ways to encrypt the CouchDB database file at rest.

I understand that CouchDB has auth rules setup to prevent unauthorised user from accessing the data.

This works well for web applications which are deployed on secure servers, but I am using CouchDB for windows app, which will be installed in multiple client machines.

With this setup, anyone(super user) can basically copy the CouchDB file and import it in another instance and access data.

Is there a way to encrypt the raw data file (through a plugin) to prevent users from snooping?